# Autocorrelation function of stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose that we have the full linear stochastic equation $$dx=-\frac{a^2}{2}xdt+axdW$$ where $a>0$ and $W(t)$ a Wiener process. Solving this equation with a change in variables $y=ln(x)$ i get $$x(t)=e^{aW(t)}$$ The autocorrelation function is $$g(τ)=<x(t)x(t+τ)>=<(e^{aW(t)})(e^{aW(t+t)})>=<e^{a(W(t)+W(t+τ))}>$$ I assumed that since the variables are independent and the last 2 terms are deterministic $$g(τ)=<e^{aW(t)}><e^{aW(t+τ)}>$$ I know that $$<e^{aW(t)}>=e^{at/2}$$ but can we assume that $<e^{aW(t+τ)}>=e^{a(t+τ)/2}$? Also, in the limit of $t{\rightarrow}{\infty}$ i should get a steady state, right?

Comment: $W(t)$ and $W(t+\tau)-W(t)$ are independent if $\tau>0$, but $W(t)$ and $W(t+\tau)$ are not independent.

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes i made a mistake there, i have fixed it now

Comment: In keeping with the first comment you should have got $g(τ)=<e^{2aW(t)}><e^{a(W(t+τ)-W(t)}>=<e^{2aW(t)}><e^{aW(τ)}>$

Comment: and then i get $g(τ)=e^{-b^2t}e^{bτ}$ if i am correct, but taking the limit of $t \rightarrow \inft$ gives $g(τ)=0$, and in this limit the power spectral density of the process is 0, which seems odd to me

Answer (score 1):

This is the geometric Brownian motion $dX=\mu Xdt+\sigma dB$ and the solution is
$$X_{t}=X_0 exp((\mu-\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2})t+\sigma B_t)$$

and so for $\mu=-a^{2}/2$ we actually get

$$X_{t}=X_0 exp(-a^{2} t+a B_t).$$

So we have
$$E[X_t X_s]=X_0^{2} e^{-a^{2}(t+s)}E[e^{a(B_t+B_s)}]$$

and use independent increments

$$E[e^{a(B_t+B_s)}]=E[e^{a(B_t-B_{s}+2B_s)}]=e^{\frac{a^{2}}{2}(t-s)+2a^{2}s}.$$